# If an Excel criteria is met in one column, record the value of the column next to the matching criteria into a range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

Perhaps I just haven't been looking in the right places, but I don't think this should be as difficult as I am finding it to be.

I have a spreadsheet, that CANNOT be sorted (it's in a production line, connected to individual sheets that bring other data in, filled out by many different people). The data that comes in is essentially random, and looks like this:

```
''    Type    Sieve #40
''
''    Truck       55%
''    Truck       55%
''    CoA         48%
''    Basement    55%
''    Bin2        55%
''    Bin1        55%
''    Hopper      57%
''    Basement    58%
''    Bin2        54%
''    Bin1        58%
''    Hopper      56%
''    Truck       56%
''    CoA         47%
''    Basement    55%
''    Bin2        57%
''    Bin1        61%
''    Hopper      50%
```

Now, I need a macro that can find the sample type (truck, bin1, etc.) and puts each value that corresponds to that sample type into a range. Then I can plot the ranges on a chart.

For example, the "Truck" range would have the numbers 55%, 55%, 56%.

So there are 6 different sample types which means 6 different ranges, which means 6 different series on my chart.

I have all the code written to plot the chart, and all the code written to gather the data into these two columns. I am just missing this piece.

Ideally, for example, there would be a way to set up a For loop that goes from row 1 to the last row of the sheet, and when it finds "truck", it assigns the number in the column next to "truck" to the first spot in a new array. Then the next instance of "truck" fills the next spot in the "Truck" array, and so on.

Adding sheets is very nearly impossible for me, because the operators must add a new sheet for each sample, which then gets some data pulled into this summary sheet.

Comment: `all the code written to plot the chart, and all the code written to gather the data into these two columns` if you did all that, why is this `easy one` giving you problems??

Comment: If you can't sort, but you can run macros, why not duplicate that sheet, turn on macro recorder, then sort the stuff.  Then take that code and use it in your sheet? Or just use that code and have it duplicate the data on a new sheet?

Comment: @BruceWayne how do you know where the ranges are to be?

Comment: cant you just use a pivot table and have both columns as 'Row Labels, that separates the data by type?

Comment: can you write in adjacent columns? or add a sheet to write in?

Comment: @user359876- I have other data in the adjacent columns.
BruceWayne- If I duplicate the sheet it won't be dynamic anymore. Right now they can input their data and click run and see a trend (if this piece of code worked)
findwindow- I was hoping that other people had a quick and easy answer, as it seems like a problem others would've had before. I'm certainly no VBA expert.

Comment: are there free column before reaching the sheet end? is it possible to add to a new temporary sheet?

Comment: @user3598756, there are other available columns further down the sheet,  around column AA. Adding sheets is not very feasible, because each individual sample is analyzed and graphed on its own new sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited** as per OP's last clarifications

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

Dim dataRng As Range, dbRng As Range, helperRng As Range, cell As Range, found As Range
Dim rangeArray() As Range
Dim iRng As Long

With Worksheets("MySheet") '<= change it to your actual worksheet name
    Set dbRng = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Resize(, 2) '<= change "A1" to your actual data first up-left cell address
    Set dataRng = dbRng.Offset(1).Resize(dbRng.Rows.Count - 1) 'extrapolate data only (headers off)
    'Set helperRng = dbRng.Offset(.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, .UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1).Cells(1, 1) ' localize "helper" range out of sheet used range
    Set helperRng = .Range("AA1") ' localize "helper" range from cell "AA1" 
End With
dataRng.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Copy Destination:=helperRng ' copy relevant data into "helper" rang

With helperRng
    If .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count > 1 Then .CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo ' take only samples unique values
    With .CurrentRegion
        ReDim rangeArray(1 To .Rows.Count) 'size the array to sample unique values number
        For iRng = 1 To .Rows.Count 'loop through sample unique values
            dbRng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=helperRng(iRng, 1) ' filter data accordingly to current sample value
            Set rangeArray(iRng) = dataRng.Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'store filtered rows columns 2 ranges
            .AutoFilter
        Next iRng
    End With
'    .ClearContents '<== remove the comment once you're done with the example
End With

' here follows an example of exploiting rangeArray array
' once you're done with it, remove this example and uncomment the ".ClearContents" statement by the end of preceeding "With ... End With" block
For iRng = 1 To UBound(rangeArray)
    rangeArray(iRng).Copy
    helperRng.Offset(iRng - 1, 1).Resize(1, rangeArray(iRng).Count).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
Next iRng

End sub
```

it'll work with whatever samples different values

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for! Worked flawlessly.

Comment: The code pastes the transposed data further down and right everytime the macro runs. Any thoughts on how to correct this? Ideally it would always show up starting at AA:1

Comment: just change the `helperRng` setting as per your needs. see edited code

Answer (score 0):

I copied your dataset into Sheet1 of a blank workbook, used text to columns, made sure Sheet2 & Sheet3 exist, and used this code to split it out. You can rework it for your needs. Essentially, I'm setting the dataset to an array, looping the values into separate arrays for each type, then loading each of those into a print array. The print array matches the `value2` dimensions. The intermediary arrays are jagged because you can't `redim preserve` a multidimensional array.

```
Sub SplitSet()
  Dim vInput() As Variant, vTruck() As Variant, vHopper() As Variant, vPrint() As Variant
  Dim l As Long

  'Get values into array
  vInput = Sheet1.UsedRange.Value2

  'Loop through array and load type arrays
  ReDim vTruck(1 To 1)
  ReDim vHopper(1 To 1)
  For l = 1 To UBound(vInput)
    Select Case vInput(l, 2)
      Case "Truck"
        If IsEmpty(vTruck(1)) = False Then ReDim Preserve vTruck(1 To UBound(vTruck) + 1)
        vTruck(UBound(vTruck)) = Array(vInput(l, 2), vInput(l, 3))
      Case "Hopper"
        If IsEmpty(vHopper(1)) = False Then ReDim Preserve vHopper(1 To UBound(vHopper) + 1)
        vHopper(UBound(vHopper)) = Array(vInput(l, 2), vInput(l, 3))
    End Select
  Next l

  'Print
  vPrint = TypeArrayToPrintArray(vTruck)
  Sheet2.Activate
  Sheet2.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(UBound(vPrint), 2)).Value2 = vPrint

  vPrint = TypeArrayToPrintArray(vHopper)
  Sheet3.Activate
  Sheet3.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(UBound(vPrint), 2)).Value2 = vPrint
End Sub

Function TypeArrayToPrintArray(ByRef vArray() As Variant) As Variant()
  Dim vPrint() As Variant
  Dim l As Long
  ReDim vPrint(1 To UBound(vArray), 1 To 2)
  For l = 1 To UBound(vArray)
    vPrint(l, 1) = vArray(l)(0)
    vPrint(l, 2) = vArray(l)(1)
  Next l

  TypeArrayToPrintArray = vPrint
End Function
```

Comment: I get a Type mismatch error once it makes it to the Function, at the vPrint command in the for loop. I also copied my data to a new spreadsheet, plus sheet 2 and 3 blank, so that it wouldn't interfere with my current stuff during testing. Is there a way to do this without adding sheets?

Comment: I wonder if you have your data lined up the same way I did; 3 columns, `'',type,%`. It's certainly possible to place the outputs somewhere else. Where do you want them?